# Using VBA to set Visible = False

Tags: vba, excel, loops, pivot-table

Edit 1:

```
Sub MultiItemPivotFilter()

Dim PI As PivotItem

For Each PI In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("test").PivotFields("date").PivotItems
    If PI.Name < ActiveSheet.Range("H14").Value Or PI.Name > ActiveSheet.Range("H15").Value Then

       PI.Visible = False
    Else
        PI.Visible = True
    End If
Next PI
End Sub
```

H14 and H15 are just fixed dates copied from the source table, but still the If condition is never true. It returns a final error, because it cant set all rows to

```
visible = false
```

End Edit 1:

I am trying to write a VBA script, which allows the user to select all observations from a pivot table between two dates. So far my script is not working.

```
Sub datelist()


Set pf = Sheets("sheet1").PivotTables("test")
Set pt = pf.PivotFields("date")
For Each pit In pt.PivotItems
    If pit.Value < Sheets("sheet1").Range("G14").Value Then pit.Visible = False
Next

End Sub
```

G14 is a cell which contains the value the user selects from the menu. I want to achieve that each row with a date lower then the selected value is set to  `Visible = False`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does your code give an error? and what is the error?

Comment: It does not give me an error, its simple does not return anything. By the way, all my fields are formatted as date cells.

Comment: Can you then please properly explain what is not working in your question. simply stating its not working doesn't really help to figure out what might be wrong

Comment: I made an edit with more details

Comment: Dates in PivotTables are funny things, and there can be issues with regional settings. I wrote a post about this that has some pretty insightful comments that might be relevant. See http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/11/09/a-date-with-pivotitems/

Comment: Thanks your input, helped a lot! I got it to work with using the DateValue function on Pivot.Name and my cell value.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with pivot tables, but is pit actually referencing a row object, or just a cell? I believe you can't just set a cell to visible = false, you have to reference the whole row / column.

you could test this by trying

```
dim rngTestRow as range
set rngTestRow = rows(pit.row)
    rngTestRow.Visible = false
```

Comment: It works when I am not using date fields, maybe pivot tables display the day fields as strings?

Comment: Can you link to a screenshot of the error message, preferably with the highlighted code it doesn't like?

Answer (score 1):

This part of code:

```
PI.Name < ActiveSheet.Range("H14").Value
```

compares `String` with `Date`.

To make it work as expected, you should convert `PI.Name` to date using `CDate` function.

```
CDate(PI.Name) < ActiveSheet.Range("H14").Value
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its works partly. Only problem is CDate returns MM/DD/YYYY, unfortunately I use DD/MM/YYYY. I could not find any option for the date format.

Comment: @user3614882 `CDate` does not return a date in specific format, but a `Date` variable type (internally stored as Integer). If you do not get correct results, then probably `H14` or `H15` does not contain valid date, but text.